# PulseAudio: Unable to Connect: Connection refused in LibGDX

Tags: java, ubuntu, libgdx, alsa, pulseaudio

I got this error in IntelliJ while trying to set up LibGDX. I'm running PopOS (Ubuntu-based). Any help?

```
ALSA lib ../../pulse/pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': Connection refused
```

Comment: Using a Ubuntu based O/S, too, I see the same error using several audio programs **after** waking up from suspend/hibernation. As @londonBadger suggests, restarting the pulseaudio daemon helps.

Answer (score 0):

check everything installed

`sudo apt install libpulse-dev pulseaudio apulse`

check its started

`systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`

check you have openJDK if you are using the Oracle one.

Its not libGDX its a java to pulseaudio issue, or more specifically OpenAL sound that libGDX uses and how it interacts with linux audio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, running on Fedora.

Apparently the issue might be cause by using `lwjgl` instead of `lwjgl3` ([this issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6426) seems like a usefull thread)

[this post](https://gist.github.com/crykn/eb37cb4f7a03d006b3a0ecad27292a2d) explains how to switch to `lwjgl3`